# AngularJS: Setting ng-readonly variable to true inside directive does not work

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a custom directive for inputs.
Inside the HTML it is used like this:
`<my-input class="input-text"
        type="number"
        ng-model="modelVariable"
        ng-readonly="false" />`

Now inside the directive myInput.js I have something like this:

```
var myInputDirective = (function() {
directives.directive('myInput', [function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: 'element',
  replace: true,
  require: 'ngModel',
  templateUrl: 'app/templates/common/myInput.tpl.html',
  scope: {
    ngModel: '=',
    ngReadonly: '='
  },

  link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ngModelController) {

    $scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue != oldValue && newValue !== undefined && newValue !== null) {
        $scope.ngReadonly = isReadOnly($attr.ngModel);
      }
    });
```

However, although this sets $scope.ngReadonly to true - the field is still not readonly - I am very confused as to why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add in the view of your directive's tempalte set `ng-readonly` equals to the parent scope as one of the attributes of your `input` element.

Just like this:

```
return {
  //..the other properties
  scope: {
    ngModel: '=',
    ngReadonly: '=readOnly'
  }
```

Then in the `myInput.tpl.html` find your `input element` and add this:

`<input ng-readonly="readOnly">`